# this is undefined inside arrow function

Tags: javascript, this, undefined, arrow-functions

I am trying to access this inside my arrow function:

```
import myObject from '../myObjectPath';
export const myClass = Fluxxor.createStore({
    initialize() {
        this.list = [];
        this.id = null;
    },
    myOutsideFunction(variable1) {
        // here this in NOT undefined
        myObject.getMyList(this.id, (myList) => {
            // here this in undefined
            this.list = myList;
        } 
    });
)};
```

But inside arrow function which in ma callback function this is undefined!!

I am using babel to transpile the code:

```
myOutsideFunction: function myOutsideFunction() {
    var _this = this;
    myObject.getMyList(function (myList) {
        _this.list = myList;
    });
},
```

Comment: Bind `this`, or store it in a temp variable outside the arrow function scope.

Comment: The value of `this` depends on how `myOutsideFunction` is called. How is it called?

Comment: @Jite the whole idea of using arrow function is to not having to bind this!

Comment: @Besat, I actually didn't know that. Thought it was just a shorthand for a standard function call. Good to  know, tyvm for that info. :)

Comment: @ Felix Kling myOutsideFunction is called from another function inside the class. But it shouldn't matter since myOutsideFunction HAS this.

Comment: @Jite Np :)) Although it does not work for me :D

Comment: According to ECMA-262 spec, arrow functions only have lexical context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `this` is `undefined` within an arrow function, it's undefined outside of the arrow as well. Arrow function simply capture the `this` of the surrounding scope.

In this case, you're declaring `myOutsideFunction` as a method on an object literal and never binding it or doing anything else that would call it with the object as `this`.

When debugging, bear in mind that transpilers can rename variables (and have to rename `this` for it to capture correctly). Using the original name in the console without sourcemaps that include renaming will show you `undefined` even if the original value isn't. Make sure you use the transpiled name in watches or console commands.

Comment: strange cause it's written `// here this in NOT undefined` just before the function call, so `this`shouldn't be undefined in the arrow function

Comment: @oliv37 strictly speaking, that's not possible. Arrow functions are a language feature and will always receive the same `this`. I'm not aware of any runtime with bugs around that (since it's pretty fundamental to arrow functions).

Comment: This is what I though!! it should not be possible! but I have tested several times and I get undefined inside arrow function however it is not undefined right before calling it

Comment: @Besat are you running this code through a transpiler or anything like that (babel, webpack, etc)? If so, can you include the output? It's possible that the compiler is changing some variable names so that it *appears* undefined in your console, but only because you're referencing the original (pre-transpile) name.

Comment: @ssube smart point! I am using babel. I will check right now.

Comment: @Besat babel will have to rename `this` since the real name is reserved, usually using `_this` instead.

Comment: @ ssube yes you are right.. I can see that in my transpiled code. but how can I fix it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121077/discussion-between-besat-and-ssube).

Comment: @Besat: So basically there was no issue with your code?

Comment: Yes.. For future record: It may not show the correct value in console since babel change this to _this

Comment: What is the solution now?? I have strucked with the same thing..getting this as undefined in arrow function

Comment: A fix is to not to use arrow function, but instead to use traditional `function() { YOUR_CODE }`