# expressjs server.js this is undefined, how can I refer to server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, this

In an ExpressJS setup, I have `server.js` where I do the following:

```
import { call_method } from '../hereIam.mjs';

const process_db = async () => {
  console.log(this); // undefined
  call_method(this);
};

console.log(this) // undefined
process_db();
```

And then, from `hereIam.mjs` I want to call a parent method, but this is undefined

```
export const call_method = parent_this => console.log(parent_this); // undefined
```

I tried to include classes in server.js, in an attempt to force having a `this`

```
class AppServer {
 constructor() {
   console.log(this)
 }

 const process_db = async () => call_method(this);
}
```

But it seems that the arrow functions inside classes doesn't compile in (experimental) NodeJS (this should be another question)

**EDITED**

How I can do this is by avoiding the arrow notation to be able to use classes inside Express, and then instantiate a class that provides a `this`.

```
class AppServer {
 async process_db() {call_method(this)};
}

let server = new AppServer();
server.process_db();
```

The question would be, **the only way of getting a `this` reference is by using objects/classes?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this is undefined inside arrow function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38978387/this-is-undefined-inside-arrow-function)

Comment: No, this is undefined BEFORE discussing arrows. I'm editing the question now

Comment: Remember, the scope is created when you use the `new` keyword

Comment: Oh, thanks, so this is about the new, thanks!

Comment: Yes you need function or class to have a this object. Lambda functions uses its outer scope. So it will use this from its outer scope.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the the [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) method and pass through any object to be used as the `this` context.

However, arrow functions receive the context from that which they are called from, `function() {}` function syntax use the context that was bound to them either implicitly by the context they were defined in or explicitly using this *bind* method.

So, an alternative to using classes would be to bind a simple object to the method, something like:

```
const call_method = require('../hereIam.mjs');

const process_db = async function() {
  console.log(this); 
  call_method(this);
};

console.log(this);

const context = {
    name: 'bound context',
    parent_method: async function() {
        console.log('Good evening');
    }
}

process_db.bind(context)();
```

Presuming `hereIam.mjs` contains:

```
module.exports = parent_this => console.log(parent_this);
```

then the script will output:

```
{}
{ name: 'bound context',
  parent_method: [AsyncFunction: parent_method] }
{ name: 'bound context',
  parent_method: [AsyncFunction: parent_method] }
```