# Why this has a value of undefined in the scope tab of google chrome dev tools? I was expecting this: window

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, this, undefined

My script below uses **reduce()** method in order to transform the array `[[0, 1],[2, 3],[4, 5]]` into `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

When debugging this script, I noticed that in the scope tab within Chrome dev tools(see screenshot below), **this** has a value of undefined. Could you explain to me why? I was expecting this: window.

P.S: I know that there is **flate()** method but my question is about **this** value.

Thank you in advance.

```
const flattened = [
  [0, 1],
  [2, 3],
  [4, 5]
].reduce(
  (acc, item) => {
    debugger;
    return acc.concat(item)
  }, []);
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: The wording could be clarified: "..this has a value of undefined .. I was expecting this: undefined."

Comment: Please clarify the ambiguity..."Why this has a value of undefined in the scope tab of google chrome dev tools? I was expecting this: undefined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using an arrow function, which have some differences compared to normal functions. Arrow functions don't have a **this** value.

If you replace the arrow function

```
(acc, item) => {
```

with a normal function,

```
function (acc, item) {
```

then 'this' will be set to 'Window'.

--

Code example and more info [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-regular-functions-and-arrow-functions/):

```
let user = { 
    name: "GFG", 
    gfg1:() => { 
        console.log("hello " + this.name); // no 'this' binding here 
    }, 
    gfg2(){        
        console.log("Welcome to " + this.name); // 'this' binding works here 
    }   
 }; 
user.gfg1(); 
user.gfg2();
```

--

EDIT: your code actually works, just the assignment to const itself doesn't have a return value, so prints "undefined" on the console. To print out the value in the const, just add it to the end:

```
const flattened = [
  [0, 1],
  [2, 3],
  [4, 5]
].reduce(
  (acc, item) => {
    return acc.concat(item)
  }, []); 
flattened
```

Output:

```
(6) [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Thanks @gregn3. The use of normal functions resolve the problem ==> this: window (see screenshot below).

Comment: Thanks @gregn3 for answering.

I agree with the fact that using regular function makes the scope display **this: window**.

However, when debugging, if I put **this** in a variable **a**  inside the arrow function, I got **a: window**:


[screenshot of the scope tab] (https://ibb.co/VpvWxD6).

Comment: @zakEls Apparently `console.log(this)` inside the arrow function also prints the **window** object. Maybe it's a bug or intentional in the Chrome debugger. Since **this** is a special variable, maybe the debugger sees it differently, than the code that is running. I found [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38978387/this-is-undefined-inside-arrow-function) discussing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are inside a arrow function, it will use lexical scoping to decide the value of this.

Whenever I see the this keyword inside of a function, these are the steps I take in order to figure out what it’s referencing. Taken from [here](https://tylermcginnis.com/this-keyword-call-apply-bind-javascript/).

1. Look to where the function was invoked.
2. Is there an object to the left of the dot? If so, that’s what the
   “this” keyword is referencing. If not, continue to #3.
3. Was the function invoked with “call”, “apply”, or “bind”? If so,
   it’ll explicitly state what the “this” keyword is referencing. If
   not, continue to #4.
4. Was the function invoked using the “new” keyword? If so, the “this”
   keyword is referencing the newly created object that was made by the
   JavaScript interpreter. If not, continue to #5.
5. Is “this” inside of an arrow function? If so, its reference may be
   found lexically in the enclosing (parent) scope. If not, continue to
    #6.
6. Are you in “strict mode”? If yes, the “this” keyword is undefined.
   If not, continue to #7.
7. JavaScript is weird. “this” is referencing the “window” object.